# Is it possible to rent a manual transmission car in Philadelphia Intl?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, phl

I'm planning to travel to Philadelphia on january and I would like to rent a car (to avoid walking around or having problems with flight timing), but searching on the net, I haven't been able to find any manual transmission car, be it sedan, sport, deluxe, a transport van, everything is automatic.

Does anybody here know where i could find a manual one?

**Edit : this question will stay here as a "how to get a manual car in PHL Intl, and will open new ones for the existing questions if required.**

Comment: I think that taking the SEPTA train is likely to be much faster and more reliable than driving, as well as far far cheaper.  Philadelphia, like most US cities, can be subject to very unpredictable traffic jams, and it's likely to be difficult and expensive to find parking.

Comment: i had heard that the train system  in the us wasn't really reliable and i didn't took it in consideration, but seems like a fairly interesting. Can i take luggage on it? *is it safe?*

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want an automatic car?

Comment: i've never drived one, and as i said to a hertz commercial agent on my local agency, "i don't feel confident with a system that doesn't let me control completely my car". aka: i would need a long tutorial on how to drive automatic cars and there's less than 1% of them where i live.

Comment: You can manually shift an automatic same as you do a manual transmission, just no clutch pedal to deal with.  I frequently manually control the auto transimissions in my vans when driving in the mountains, as well as when i want a burst of power for passing. But enjoy not having to worry about mundane shifting while driving in cities.

Comment: the problem is that in my way of driving (and of anybody here) , the clutch pedal is the most vital part of the car, used to reduce speed, to park / unpark, etc...

Comment: it's not the difficulty of it, i'm sure it's easy as hell compared  to manual driving, it's just that i have no training on it (neither my friend) and none of us want to end with the rental car attached to a tree while trying to park.

Comment: The point is that it's so easy that you need no training.

Comment: What @relaxed says - if you can drive a manual, you can drive an auto. Yes, in a manual, you use cluch for a lot of control. In an Auto you don't miss that control, because you don't need it - accelerator is go and brake is stop - the car itself makes sure you don't stall. I am saying all this as someone who learned in a manual and had no training in an auto.

Comment: Incidentally, I know many people who try to make up some sophisticated arguments for manual transmission but *nobody* ever told me they had serious difficulties switching to an automatic transmission car, let alone had an accident because of it. If you are genuinely concerned about your ability to drive one safely – as opposed to being snobbish – you could trust the people who have done both and tell you it's not a problem.

Comment: And regarding @NateEldredge's train suggestion. While the US inter-city passenger Train system isn't very good (in that it's slow, and unreliable with regards to late arrivals etc compared to most European networks, although it does have a good safety record), what is being suggested is that you take a local, mass-transit system, more like taking a tram/underground etc.

Comment: so, regarding the mass transit system suggested,  does it have any luggage limits? is it safe enough?   (even my country's mass transit depending on the city is not really recomended for tourists that are just passing by and are in a hurry / might not have 100% attention on their pockets / whatever they have on sight)

Comment: @CptEric - that's probably best to ask another question about, not discuss in comments. (Also, if asking about safety, please define what you mean/want to know. "Safe" is a value judgement, that many people take very, very differently)

Comment: @CptEric: How are you using the clutch for braking? I use my brakes for that?

Comment: it's called engine braking, you release the gear, and shift one gear down, releasing the clutch will start slowing down the vehicle, let's say, to get to a  distant stop signal, or a semaphore, or to loose power / G-force on a more-than-average closed turn without having to brake.

Comment: @phresnel: when driving down a slope, you can see signs with "Use your engine break" which means set a "lower" gear to slow down the car rather than rely on breaks (because breaking for an extended period of time might very well break the breaks, and going downhill it's a pickle).

Comment: @Relaxed: `let alone had an accident because of it`: Well, if you do performance driving (hopefully on a race track), a sudden (unexpected) shift can unbalance your car just enough to let your car lose traction.  It's also hard to prepare down shifts, especially when heel & toe shifting. All in all, I find manual transmission cars more reliable to predict w.r.t. acceleration. Anyways, if you are a normal driver driving normally, there should be no problem.

Comment: @phresnel What are you talking about? Was that meant as an answer to MatthieuM.?

Comment: @CptEric: Yes, but then you are using the engine, not the clutch, as the name suggests. Indeed, out of my head I don't know how to do that with automatic cars, but it's not the _clutch_ you use for that, but the _engine_.

Comment: it's the clutch pedal in combination with the gear stick, that forces the engine to go down on revolutions, so it's more because of the clutch as itself than the engine.

Comment: @CptEric: Uhm, first it was the clutch, now it's the clutch pedal. But in the end it's friction from the engine that slows down the car. It's a nitpicky discussion we are having, sorry.

Comment: @CptEric Note that engine braking is never supposed to be the main way to stop a vehicle. I learned to drive in Europe with a manual transmission car and lived half my life in a mountainous area so I am very familiar with it but it's just an advanced technique, not something you should rely on in a big way or the most vital control of the car. As a matter of fact, basic training in my locale involves performing an emergency stop during which you are explicitly told not to worry about the clutch.

Comment: mountainous area vs flat area, that's the thing. here it's the most common thing to both ease brake stress and fuel consumption.

Comment: @phresnel Presumably, if you do “performance driving” (quite obviously not the topic of the discussion and a very bad idea on regular roads with a rental in a foreign country), you presumably know enough about cars and driving to be able to adapt to an automatic transmission, so I still don't see the relevance of this far-fetched scenario to the context of my comment.

Comment: @phresnel If your automatic car offers a manual override, you can engine brake by down--shifting. I've done it descending long/steep hills in automatics a few times.

Comment: this discussion is really getting off topic.  i will gladly accept a good answer that involves either a valid and well explained alternative to the rental, a rental location with manual , average priced cars,  or a guide to adapt to automatic driving coming from manual european driving , preferably if it's of one of the avaliable, under 100$ automatic cars on PHL airport, as the three are in-topic with the travel tag.

Comment: I'd honestly ask seperate questions about all those things. They're good, on topic questions, and you can make your decision about which option to take based off the answers you get.

Comment: let met get to a computer, CMaster, and i'll do so. this will remain as the 2nd one.

Comment: I've just been to the U.S. and rented an automatic, and it wasn't as bad as I'd feared. They have long straight roads, slightly lower speed limits than we do in Europe and the cars don't accelerate as fast (bigger & heavier?) so I wasn't scared of losing control and crashing. The brakes felt softer than usual though. The worst parts were merging into the interstate, since it's a different direction to the U.K. and the was very little visibility over my shoulder through the car, and getting used to no real rear indicator lights on cars in front - some cars flash the tail lights to indicate (!).

Comment: Automatics do engine braking all the time when you take your foot off the accelerator.  The only thing you loose is coasting, which you should not be doing in a manual anyway.  The only thing to get used to is creep and all you need to know is apply the brake at all times when you are at a standstill. Training done. :)

Comment: The shifter is Park, Reverse, Neutral, Drive, and numbered low gears which nobody ever uses. Park is what it sounds like. The car _will_ have a handbrake, but nobody uses it unless parked on a steep hill, and often not even then. You have to apply the brake to shift out of Park. If you're accelerating fairly hard, you can upshift simply by easing off the accelerator, or downshift by giving it more gas. Play with this while driving up a slight hill to get a feel for it. I drive both manual and automatic, and I don't really think you'll have a problem.

Comment: @Rup In the US, rear indicator lights are not required to be amber as they are in Europe, so some cars simply flash the left or right tail light to indicate a turn, especially with older cars.  But amber indicator lights are common enough.

Comment: Comments should be on the original post. Please take extended conversations to chat.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31444/discussion-on-question-by-cpteric-is-it-possible-to-rent-a-manual-transmission-c).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The majority of US made cars have an automatic transmission as standard equipment. Manual transmissions are available but usually by special order.

Car rental companies in the US tend to buy cars with automatics, since that is the preference of US drivers.  And while yes there are European tourists who rent cars in the US and prefer manual transmissions, they are really just a small percentage of the rental customers. The reverse was true for many years in Europe in that only manual transmissions were available and Americans traveling in Europe had no choice but to drive a stick.

There are some smaller rental companies that may offer manual transmissions at some locations or on some models, but at airport rental locations, it is usually the biggest companies and they pretty much offer automatics.

Comment: "There are some smaller rental companies that may offer manual transmissions at some locations or on some models", any on PHL? searching through the net only the big ones appear.

Comment: At airports you are stuck with the big boys.  You have to look for off airport smaller car rental companies.